# Wi-Fi adapter fails to obtain an IP address in Windows after being used in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, wireless-networking, drivers

My tablet has a Broadcom BCM43455 chip, but doesn't have the configuration file stored in NVRAM as expected by the Linux (Xubuntu) `brcmfmac` driver. As a workaround, I decided to copy the file from my Windows 10 installation (where it's stored at `Windows\System32\drivers\4345r6nvram.txt`) to where the `brcmfmac` driver was expecting it (not in NVRAM - the driver also checks if the file `/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt` exists). After a quick `modprobe`, my Wi-Fi was now up and running, and so far it seems to be working perfectly.

However, the problem is, now that the device works in Linux, it fails to get an IP address from my router in Windows. When I try to disable the device in Device Manager (often fixes things) the program crashes, and if I try to reboot the computer after this I get a long wait, followed by a blue screen of death telling me about a `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE`.

The only solution to get my Windows Wi-Fi back seems to be to reinstall the driver (also crashes, but if I disable the driver and reboot, after the BSOD when the tablet restarts the device has been disabled. Once I've done that, uninstalling the driver works). But then when I next boot into Linux, the same thing happens all over again.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I am having the opposite problem, works on windows, but cant get an IP on Linux...  I too also had to copy the sdio.txt file, I have tried several found on the internet... no luck...  Did you end up figuring this out?